# Entity with optional attribute crashes in Snow Leopard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, core-data

Alright, so my issue is fairly simple. I need one of my attributes to be optional. Under 10.7 & 10.8 it's fine, but under Snow Leopard it crashes. When I uncheck "optional", then it doesn't crash anymore but now saving causes an error and doesn't happen.

This is how I set up managed object context:

```
self.notesPersistentStore = [self.notesStoreCoordinator
                              addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                              configuration:nil
                              URL:self.notesStoreUrl
                              options:nil
                              error:nil];

_notesContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
_notesContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;
[_notesContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.notesStoreCoordinator];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                       selector:@selector(notesContextChanged:)
                                       name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                       object:self.notesContext];
```

And this is the part where it crashes:

```
- (void)notesContextChanged:(NSNotification *)notification_
{
    [self.notesContext save:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

Snow Leopard want's the save of NSManagedObjectContext to happen on the main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSError *error;
    [self.notesContext save:&error];
    [Utils handleError:error];
});
```

And now it works!

The thing that baffles me is that if all attributes are specified as mandatory it works just great without being run on the main thread, even on 10.6. Oh well...